# Folium TimestampedGeoJson Will Not Increment Exactly One Month

Tags: python, folium, folium-plugins

As the timeline increments, instead of following the `dates` values which are on day 1 of each month, the timeline moves from 11/1 to 11/30 and continues "off" the programmed dates until we hit 4/1/24.

I tried `times` in place of `dates`, no change.

Reason I'm doing this is the project I'm working on will be plotting many LineStrings and I need to show changes in [various parameters] month to month, always on day 1.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson

def create_geojson() -> dict:
    lines: list = [
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2017-09-01T00:00:00", "2017-10-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2017-10-01T00:00:00", "2017-11-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2017-11-01T00:00:00", "2017-12-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2017-12-01T00:00:00", "2018-01-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2018-01-01T00:00:00", "2018-02-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2018-02-01T00:00:00", "2018-03-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2018-03-01T00:00:00", "2018-04-01T00:00:00"]},
        {"coordinates": [[139.76451, 35.68159],[139.75964, 35.68259]],
            "dates": ["2018-04-01T00:00:00", "2018-05-01T00:00:00"]}
    ]

    features: list = [
            {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                        "type": "LineString",
                        "coordinates": line["coordinates"],
                        },
            "properties": {
                        "times": line["dates"],
                        "style": {
                                "weight": 10
                                },
                        },
            }
            for line in lines
        ]

    pipelines: dict = {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": features,
            }

    return pipelines

def create_timeline_map():

    m: folium.Map = folium.Map(location=[35.6815965, 139.7645151], zoom_start=16)
    pipelines: dict = create_geojson()

    TimestampedGeoJson(
            pipelines,
            period="P1M",
            ).add_to(m)

    m.save('timeline_map-manual.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    create_timeline_map()
```

I've tried many different combinations for `period` and `duration`, but no matter what I do, I cannot get the timeline to follow the values in 'dates`.  How can I get the timeline to work correctly and increment from day 1 on one month to day 1 on the next month?

**edit**: I removed the `period` data from `TimestampedGeoJson` and watched the time slider moving forward.  On 11/5 it jumps from 2023-11-05 00:00:00 to 2023-11-05 23:00:00 instead of moving to 2023-11-06 00:00:00.  Hopefully that will provide a clue as to what's going on?

**edit2**: My esteemed colleague observed that this is most likely due to daylight savings time.  If this is the case, is there a way to get `TimestampedGeoJson` to ignore daylight savings time?  Or better yet, ignore `duration` and `period` and just use the time stamps from the dictionary?